# Coturn server not listening on TLS ports on Debian 10

Tags: debian-buster, coturn, rfc5766turnserver

I have a problem connecting to my turnserver on TLS ports. I have upgraded my Debian server to Buster recently and noticed that coturn is only listening port 3478. Both stun and turn work well. However, coturn is not listening 5378 and turns is not working. I tried reinstalling coturn completely, but no success. Certificate is valid, from certbot. The same behavior with default config file. And there are no error message either in verbose or in Verbose modes. Needless to say, there is nothing else listening at the TLS ports. So, now I feel completely stuck with it... Has anybody seen such behavior? Or how can I trace what makes coturn not start listening on TLS?

Answer (score 9):

Looks like I discovered a silly problem: since coturn runs under turnserver user, one has to adjust certificate ownerships, because by default certificates obtained with certbot belong to root with 644 access rights. Bad thing is that coturn didn't digest it when  created a symlink to the certificate with proper ownership, so I had to copy actual cert files. Not elegant at all. Otherwise, everything seems to work flawlessly, including web interface.

Answer (score 0):

```
nano /lib/systemd/system/coturn.service

#append this line
User=root
Group=root
```